# `/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-1000.slice/pids.max` changed after re connect to machine (ssh)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I want to edit `/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-1000.slice/pids.max`. the file reset every time I exit the machine.
is there a proper way to keep the changes without run script during boot as root? 
How to configure pids.max for `user.slice`?

Comment: it rests when I ssh to machine

Answer (score 0):

write in /etc/init.d/rcS

ls -sf /etc/pids.max /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-1000.slice/pids.max

lol

Comment: Can't. the path doesn't exit while reboots. I noticed that ssh overwrite this file